# how call unity3D from IOS application?

Tags: ios

My swift source is below.

```
import Foundation
import UnityFramework
class UnityEmbeddedSwift: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UnityFrameworkListener {
    public struct UnityMessage {
        let objectName : String?
        let methodName : String?
        let messageBody : String?
    }
    public static var instance : UnityEmbeddedSwift!
    public var ufw : UnityFramework!
    public static var hostMainWindow : UIWindow!
    public static var launchOpts : [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
    public static var cachedMessages = [UnityMessage]()
    
static func getUnityRootViewController() -> UIViewController! {
        return instance.ufw.appController()?.rootViewController
    }

    static func getUnityView() -> UIView! {
        return instance.ufw.appController()?.rootViewController?.view
    }

    static func setHostMainWindow(_ hostMainWindow : UIWindow?) {
        UnityEmbeddedSwift.hostMainWindow = hostMainWindow
        let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.landscapeLeft.rawValue
        UIDevice.current.setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")
    }

    static func setLaunchinOptions(_ launchingOptions :  [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) {
        UnityEmbeddedSwift.launchOpts = launchingOptions
    }

    static func showUnity() {
        if(UnityEmbeddedSwift.instance == nil || UnityEmbeddedSwift.instance.unityIsInitialized() == false) {
            UnityEmbeddedSwift().initUnityWindow()
        }
        else {
            UnityEmbeddedSwift.instance.showUnityWindow()
        }
    }

    static func hideUnity() {
        UnityEmbeddedSwift.instance?.hideUnityWindow()
    }

    static func pauseUnity() {
        UnityEmbeddedSwift.instance?.pauseUnityWindow()
    }

    static func unpauseUnity() {
        UnityEmbeddedSwift.instance?.unpauseUnityWindow()
    }

    static func unloadUnity() {
        UnityEmbeddedSwift.instance?.unloadUnityWindow()
        print("unloadUnity")
      //  UnityEmbeddedSwift.instance?.applicationWillTerminate(UIApplication.shared)
    }

    static func sendUnityMessage(_ objectName : String, methodName : String, message : String) {
        let msg : UnityMessage = UnityMessage(objectName: objectName, methodName: methodName, messageBody: message)

        // Send the message right away if Unity is initialized, else cache it
        if(UnityEmbeddedSwift.instance != nil && UnityEmbeddedSwift.instance.unityIsInitialized()) {
            UnityEmbeddedSwift.instance.ufw.sendMessageToGO(withName: msg.objectName, functionName: msg.methodName, message: msg.messageBody)
        }
        else {
            UnityEmbeddedSwift.cachedMessages.append(msg)
        }
    }

    // MARK - Callback from UnityFrameworkListener

    func unityDidUnload(_ notification: Notification!) {
        
        print("unityDidUnload")
        ufw.unregisterFrameworkListener(self)
        ufw = nil
        UnityEmbeddedSwift.hostMainWindow?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        
      //  AppDelegate *blah = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication, sharedApplication]delegate];


    }

    // MARK: - Private functions (called within the class)

    private func unityIsInitialized() -> Bool {
        return ufw != nil && (ufw.appController() != nil)
    }

    private func initUnityWindow() {
        if unityIsInitialized() {
            showUnityWindow()
            return
        }
        ufw = UnityFrameworkLoad()!
       // ufw.setDataBundleId("com.unity3d.framework2")
        ufw.setDataBundleId("com.unity3d.framework")
        ufw.register(self)
        ufw.runEmbedded(withArgc: CommandLine.argc, argv: CommandLine.unsafeArgv, appLaunchOpts: UnityEmbeddedSwift.launchOpts)

        sendUnityMessageToGameObject()

        UnityEmbeddedSwift.instance = self
    }

    private func showUnityWindow() {
        if unityIsInitialized() {
            ufw.showUnityWindow()
            sendUnityMessageToGameObject()
        }
    }

    private func hideUnityWindow() {
        if(UnityEmbeddedSwift.hostMainWindow == nil) {
            print("WARNING: hostMainWindow is nil! Cannot switch from Unity window to previous window")
        }
        else {
            UnityEmbeddedSwift.hostMainWindow?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }
    }

    private func pauseUnityWindow() {
        ufw.pause(true)
    }

    private func unpauseUnityWindow() {
        ufw.pause(false)
    }

    private func unloadUnityWindow() {
        print("unloadUnityWindow")
        if unityIsInitialized() {
            print("unloadUnityWindow    IFIFIF")
            UnityEmbeddedSwift.cachedMessages.removeAll()
            ufw.unloadApplication()
        }
    }

    private func sendUnityMessageToGameObject() {
        if (UnityEmbeddedSwift.cachedMessages.count >= 0 && unityIsInitialized())
        {
            for msg in UnityEmbeddedSwift.cachedMessages {
                ufw.sendMessageToGO(withName: msg.objectName, functionName: msg.methodName, message: msg.messageBody)
            }

            UnityEmbeddedSwift.cachedMessages.removeAll()
        }
    }

    private func UnityFrameworkLoad() -> UnityFramework? {
        let bundlePath: String = Bundle.main.bundlePath +  "/Frameworks/UnityFramework.framework"     // "/Frameworks/UnityFramework.framework"   //
        print(bundlePath)
        
        let bundle = Bundle(path: bundlePath )
        if bundle?.isLoaded == false {
            bundle?.load()
        }

        let ufw = bundle?.principalClass?.getInstance()
        if ufw?.appController() == nil {
            // unity is not initialized
            //            ufw?.executeHeader = &mh_execute_header

            let machineHeader = UnsafeMutablePointer<MachHeader>.allocate(capacity: 1)
            machineHeader.pointee = _mh_execute_header

            ufw!.setExecuteHeader(machineHeader)
        }
        return ufw
    }
```

}

And I am calling with showUnitywindows().
However, it works on ios 6 and not on ios 8. Why is that?

Comment: It works fine in ios 6.